# is there a PySpark function that will merge data from a column for rows with same id?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have the following dataframe:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | f |
| 2 | g |
| 3 | j |
+---+---+
```

I need it to be in a df/rdd format

```
(1, [a, b, c])
(2, [f, g])
(3, [j])
```

I'm new to spark and was wondering if this operation can be performed by a single function

I tried using flatmap but I don't think I'm using it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by "A" and then use aggregate function for example collect_set or collect_array

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = [
    {"A": 1, "B": "a"},
    {"A": 1, "B": "b"},
    {"A": 1, "B": "c"},
    {"A": 2, "B": "f"},
    {"A": 2, "B": "g"},
    {"A": 3, "B": "j"}
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
df.groupBy("A").agg(F.collect_set(F.col("B"))).show()
```

Output

```
+---+--------------+
|  A|collect_set(B)|
+---+--------------+
|  1|     [c, b, a]|
|  2|        [g, f]|
|  3|           [j]|
+---+--------------+
```

Comment: Great use of dataframes.  I like Spark SQL also.

Answer (score 0):

First step, create sample data.

```
#
# 1 - Create sample dataframe + view
#

# array of tuples - data
dat1 = [
    (1, "a"),
    (1, "b"),
    (1, "c"),
    (2, "f"),
    (2, "g"),
    (3, "j")  
]

# array of names - columns
col1 = ["A", "B"]

# make data frame
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=dat1, schema=col1)

# make temp hive view
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("sample_data")
```

Second step, play around with temporary table.

```
%sql
select * from sample_data
```

[image]

```
%sql
select A, collect_list(B) as B_LIST from sample_data group by A
```

[image]

Last step, write code to execute Spark SQL to create dataframe that you want.

```
df2 = spark.sql("select A, collect_list(B) as B_LIST from sample_data group by A")
display(df2)
```

[image]

In summary, you can use the dataframe methods to create the same output.  However, the Spark SQL looks clean and makes more sense.